# GeoNearest[] between current location and a list of GeoPositions[]: Documented example is not producing documented output

Tags: geography, geographics

First off I am doing this for recreational purposes only, so it's not the end of the world if I cannot figure this out. I am trying to utilize the `GeoNearest[]` function to calculate the nearest point in a list of geographic coordinates (this list looks like `{GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}]...}` ) to my current location (I define my current location here as  `$GeoLocation`).

At first I thought this would be straightforward, as one of the examples in the `GeoNearest[]` documentation is exactly the same as what I'm attempting to accomplish. This example can be found under the subsection "Groups of Entities and Regions" under "Scope":

```
 GeoNearest[{GeoPosition[{34.14, 35.29}], GeoPosition[{34.56, 37.62}],
   GeoPosition[{35.71, 34.55}], GeoPosition[{31.06, 39.56}], 
  GeoPosition[{39.53, 37.90}]}, $GeoLocation]
```

According to the documentation, this should return the nearest point in the list to my location.

However, evaluating this example produces the following error (all of the following examples are from a fresh kernel):

**GeoNearest::geonear1: GeoPosition[{34.14,35.29}] is not a valid entity type pattern, a valid list of locations, or a valid list of rules.**

removing the first element from the list of points doesn't fix this:

```
 GeoNearest[{GeoPosition[{34.56, 37.62}],
   GeoPosition[{35.71, 34.55}], GeoPosition[{31.06, 39.56}], 
  GeoPosition[{39.53, 37.90}]}, $GeoLocation]
```

**GeoNearest::geonear1: GeoPosition[{34.56,37.62}] is not a valid entity type pattern, a valid list of locations, or a valid list of rules.**

I have also confirmed `$GeoLocation` is working correctly (hiding last sig fig with an "x" so you can't see exactly where I am:

```
In[1]:= $GeoLocation

Out[1]= GeoPosition[{42.2x, -83.7x}]
```

I feel like the exact value of `$GeoLocation` should not matter when trying to get the documented example to work. So my inclination is that it is not a problem on the $GeoLocation side but I am wrong more often than I like to admit.

[GeoNearest[] documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoNearest.html)

I do not know what is wrong. I have never used any of Mathematica's Geo features so it could very well be a knowledge issue. If anyone has any idea that would be great. Or at least maybe different things I can test to try and start to diagnose the problem?

Update: I have made an example code here on calculating the minimum distance point (using Syed's suggestion of calculating GeoDistance to each point) on US territory (including outer lying islands) to Tokyo if anyone is interested in seeing what I'm trying to do (please don't be too mean to me about my subideal syntax XD).
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/20c3c85a-2b10-4b35-bd59-06dfe7541d3d

Probably should've added this from the start: I am running Mathematica 13.2 on macOS Ventura 13.1

Final Update: After forwarding to wolfram support, the documented example

```
GeoNearest[{GeoPosition[{34.56, 37.62}],
  GeoPosition[{35.71, 34.55}], GeoPosition[{31.06, 39.56}], 
 GeoPosition[{39.53, 37.90}]}, $GeoLocation]
```

produces the expected output. I do not know what the specific issue was however as this was not communicated to me unfortunately. Thank you to whoever fixed this at Wolfram though!

Comment: I think you shold report this to: support@wolfram.com  and let us know what they reply.

Comment: Try: `cities = Flatten@(GeoNearest["City", #] & /@
     {GeoPosition[{34.14, 35.29}], GeoPosition[{34.56, 37.62}],
         GeoPosition[{35.71, 34.55}], GeoPosition[{31.06, 39.56}]});` and then for instance: `GeoNearest[cities, Entity["City", {"Beirut", "Beirut", "Lebanon"}]]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I have sent a message thanks

Comment: @Syed thank you. `GeoNearest[cities, GeoNearest["City", $GeoLocation]]` works correctly, though I wish I could figure out how to use the raw GeoPositions instead of nearest cities. I'm guessing GeoPosition[] is no longer recognized as a valid entity (which I guess is pretty much what the error message is saying)? And maybe that change has not yet been reflected in the GeoNearest documentation? I was reading the GeoPosition documentation as well but maybe I need to read it a little more closely to see how mathematica treats GeoPositions

Comment: maybe a work around: could I create my own custom entity based off GeoPosition coordinates that would work for GeoNearest? I do not know how to create custom entities but I think this is something that can be done, correct?

Comment: Perhaps: `GeoDistance[{GeoPosition[{34.14, 35.29}], GeoPosition[{34.56, 37.62}],
      GeoPosition[{35.71, 34.55}], GeoPosition[{31.06, 39.56}]}, 
  GeoPosition[{31.95`, 35.93`}]] // Normal`  and then sort.

Comment: @Syed yes it looks like
`dists = GeoDistance[gpsList, GeoPosition[{31.95, 35.93}]] // 
   Normal;`

`gpsList[[First@Ordering@dists]]` 
returns the nearest GeoPosition[]. I was just worried this would be the less efficient since it has to go through evaluate the distance for all points. But I guess I really don't know if there's any sort of search optimization in GeoNearest anyways.

Comment: `gpsList` is just a list of the GeoPositions i am calculating the distance from sorry forgot to mention that above. And I would guess since there's no guarantees on the spatial distribution of the list of points gpsList there in general can't be too much optimization involved in GeoNearest vs brute forcing and calculating every distance, but I don't actually know.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue here.  I have run the code from this post in versions 13 through 13.2 and it returns a value as expected.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for the info. I am running 13.2 on macOS Ventura 13.1. I have sent a message to wolfram support. Maybe it's just an issue on my OS

Comment: Same issue on Win 11 Home, v13.1 and v13.2.

Comment: As an alternative for lists of GeoPosition objects, Nearest can be used instead of GeoNearest. But GeoNearest should work as well.